# Setting an Hourly x-Axis to plot Accumarray in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, accumarray

In matlab I have used accumarray() to create a new vector with 3 columns of integers. Column 1: date (just the day); Column 2: hour; Column 3: Sample Value.

```
19.0000    9.0000   25.6937
19.0000   10.0000   30.2616
19.0000   11.0000   32.2840
19.0000   12.0000   28.4867
19.0000   14.0000   35.4055
19.0000   16.0000   48.3377
```

Right now my code for plotting the graph involves the following;

```
xdate = datenum(year,month,day,hourVector,minutes,seconds);

plot(xdate,sampleValue,'-x','MarkerSize',10)

datetick('x','ddd HHPM')
```

I'm having trouble finding a method where the x-axis is labeled once every hour (or 2 hours). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just want the x ticks to be spaced by 1 hour, independently of the data spacing? From your example, I don't see that you necessarily have a data point once an hour.

If my understanding is correct, try replacing

```
datetick('x','ddd HHPM')
```

with the following:

```
hr_step = 0.0417; % increasing datenum by this amount will advance date by 1 hour
tick_xdate = min(xdate):hr_step:max(xdate);
set(gca,'XTick',tick_xdate)
datetick('x','ddd HHPM','keepticks') % 'keepticks' option forces the use of tick_xdate
```